# How to search for specific string but only return 1 email per email address?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

Does the gmail API allow for a way to search for a string and return all the mail that has this string but limit the list to 1 email per email address.

For example, I want to find all mail that contain a certain username but the list only contains one email per address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for these types of complex queries with the Gmail API, sadly.

Something along these lines will get it done though:

1. [List messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) with your search string as the `q`-parameter until there is no `nextPageToken` in the response (then you will have gotten every result of the query).
2. [Get all matching messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get), only asking for the `From`-header, and find all unique senders yourself ([batch requests](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/batch?hl=en) would work great for this use case).

**Example**

**List message ids**

```
q = feel the bern
fields = messages(id),nextPageToken

GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=feel+the+bern&fields=messages(id)%2CnextPageToken&access_token={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

**Response**

```
{
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": "151c1de994ad5e43"
  },
  {
   "id": "1514f614e6c07c3f"
  }, ...
 ]
}
```

**Get every message (in batch)**

```
format = metadata
metadataHeaders = from
fields = id,payload/headers

GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/151c1de994ad5e43?format=metadata&metadataHeaders=from&fields=id%2Cpayload%2Fheaders&access_token={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

**Response**

```
{
 "id": "151c1de994ad5e43",
 "payload": {
  "headers": [
   {
    "name": "From",
    "value": "Official Bernie Store <info@berniesanders.com>"
   }
  ]
 }
},
{
 "id": "151c1de994ad3e22",
 "payload": {
  "headers": [
   {
    "name": "From",
    "value": "Emil Tholin <emtholin@gmail.com>"
   }
  ]
 }
}, ...
```

Then you can just filter messages out by email address, and then get the entire mail of the ones that are left.